# javascript to input text into a textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I am pretty new at javascript, so forgive me if this seems simple. What I'm trying to do is to get the input box to have a value of 'hello', when submit_a is clicked, but it's not happening.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var Text = 'hello'.
  function setInput(button) {
     var buttonVal = button.value,
     textbox = document.getElementById('input_' + buttonVal);
     textbox.value = Text ;
}
</script>

<html>
 <input type="submit" name="submit_a" value="click-me" onclick="setInput(this); return 
  false;"> 
 <input type="text" name="a" id="input_a">
</html>
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code: `var Text = 'hello'.` : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier `. Also, `buttonVal` is `click-me` and you have no element with ID `input_click-me`, only `input_a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make that work change the JavaScript to:

```
var Text = 'hello';

function setInput(button) {
   var buttonVal = button.name,
   textbox = document.getElementById('input_' + buttonVal);
   textbox.value = Text ;
}
```

... and the HTML to:

```
<input type="submit" name="a" value="click-me" onclick="setInput(this); return false;"> 
<input type="text" id="input_a">
```

Answer (score 1):

Comment mentions the dot after 'hello' being wrong and the button value.

You also left out the 'a' after the underline chars.

The unneeded 'button.value' had a comma after it.

```
var Text = 'hello';
  function setInput(button) {
     textbox = document.getElementById('input_a');
     textbox.value = Text ;
}
```